# How to trigger code wrapped in one event with another onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have this code wrapped in HOVER Event...

```
$("#div_ID").hover(function() {
  // perform stuff here...
}
);
```

I'd like to trigger the above when I click a link using the ONCLICK Event...

```
$("anchor_ID").click (function() {
 $("div_ID").trigger('hover'); // Not sure if this is even correct
}
);
```

It's not working though. How can I accomplish this? Is it even possible?
Using JQuery only on FF v16, IE8, and GC v23

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var dosomething = function() {
    // perform the stuff here
}

$('#div_ID').hover(dosomething);
$('anchor_ID').click(dosomething);
```

But if you are set on using `.trigger`, your problem might be that you forgot to include `#` before `div_ID`.  And change `hover` to `mouseenter` (the "hover" function in jQuery is just a shortcut for "mouseenter" -- credit to @FabrícioMatté for catching that) That is:

```
//change this:
$('div_ID').trigger('hover');
//To this:
$('#div_ID').trigger('mouseenter');
```

Same might apply to `anchor_ID`, but I won't know unless you post your HTML.

**Update**: another suggestion from @FabrícioMatté: the `this` keyword inside of `dosomething` might be a bit confusing when you call it as shown above, so watch out for it.  The `this` keyword will work differently than using `.trigger`, so it's just a heads up....

Comment: Why do you use `var dosomething = function() {}` instead of `function doSomething() {}`?

Comment: @jfriend00: because I felt like it?  Honestly, I think the logic of passing variable-functions is easier than the logic of passing functions.  But that's just me...

Comment: This is a good solution and I'd normally go with this one, but one extra note to add: in case OP uses the `this` keyword inside the handler function, attaching the same function to those 2 elements will have a different result than triggering the handler attached to another element. +1 for the reusable code nevertheless.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: good point to make. I *assumed* that would be obvious, but I guess the `this` keyword is never obvious... I'll update my answer.

Comment: And it's also obvious that this a better solution overall as it doesn't generate an unnecessary synthetic event nor risks triggering unintended handlers, but I felt like posting an answer to explain more in-depth why the `.trigger('hover')` doesn't work. `=]`

Comment: @cegfault - Thanks! Nice elegant solution. Correct on both counts.

Answer (score 1):

`hover` is not an event so you can't [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) it. [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is just a shorthand which attaches `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` handlers.

```
$("#anchor_ID").click(function() {
    $("#div_ID").trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AhEuq/)

Note that `.hover` when passed a single argument will attach the function to both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` so you can trigger either of these.
I'd recommend attaching the handler with [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) instead of `hover` if you intend to execute the handler only when users move their mouse above the `div`.